# Array of multiple text files from get-content

Tags: arrays, powershell, file-io

As the title suggests I want to save the content of multiple text files into a 2 dimensional array.

```
$script[0] = Get-Content "test1.txt"
$script[1] = Get-Content "test2.txt"
```

Which results in the error `Cannot index into a null array.`
Apperantly this is due to the fact that the array isn't initialized.

so I tried:

```
$script = @()
```

and

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $scriptcount; $i++) 
{ 
  $script += @() 
}
```

and eventually

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $scriptcount; $i++) 
{ 
  $script += @(@()) 
}
```

but all of above ended up with the error `Index was outside the bounds of the array.`

So what can I do to save these files into my 2d array?

*A small side question* : with these 2d arrays is it possible to generate the count of arrays?

because `$script.Count` ends up with the length of the first sentence instead of the amount of arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for your issues is that the return value from Get-Content is an array of strings, if the file contains more than a single line of text.

Simply use the -Raw parameter of Get-Content (Available from version 3.0) which will read the entire content of the file into a string.

```
$script[0] = Get-Content "test1.txt" -Raw
$script[1] = Get-Content "test2.txt" -Raw
```

Or you can assign it to a 2d array as simple as

```
$script = @((Get-Content "test1.txt), (Get-Content "test2.txt"))
```

Now $script[0] contains the content of test1.txt and so forth.

As for your side question. Total Count of elements can be calculated by

```
$total=0;$script | % {$total += $_.Count};$total
```

If you just need the Count of files read using Get-Content, you can use `$script.Count`

Comment: that would work but I want to keep it as an array of strings. I just want to make it a 2d array (an array of multiple strings arrays)

Comment: Thank you! also I may have word the side question a bit wrongly but I meant: can I generate the number of text files I've read with get content?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$script = -join (Get-Content $scriptfile)`, this should make the value of `$script` a giant string with embedded newlines, instead of an array of strings. If the strings themselves do not have newlines, then the binary `-join` is needed: `$script = (Get-Content $scriptfile) -join "\n"`

Other alternatives:

```
$script = Get-Content $filename | Out-String
$script = Get-Content -ReadCount 0 # default is 1, which reads each line
$script = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($filename) | Out-string # or -join "\n"
```

The official documentation is available at [about_join](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847757.aspx) on MSDN.

However, depending on the size of the files, this could be memory intensive.